# In MVC partial view, how to find main view's element, and change its boolean value?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view and I want to find a specific element in the parent view, and change its value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.editBtn, .cancelBtn').on('click', function () {
           $(/*parent's body id???*/)find('#Smoker').val('true');
        });
});
```

In this case `#Smoker` is the element I want to have its value modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referencing an element by its ID, then simply use the ID attribute itself (as [ID attributes are unique by definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)) :

```
$('.editBtn, .cancelBtn').on('click', function () {
       // This should always work as #Smoker should be unique
       $('#Smoker').val('true');
});
```

If you really want to use the parent, then you can use the [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) or [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) functions to scope where you want to search for your element at relative to the element that triggered the function :

```
$('.editBtn, .cancelBtn').on('click', function () {
       // Find the #Smoker element using the parent
       $('#Smoker',$(this).parent()).val('true');
       // Find the #Smoker element within the closest parent <div>
       $('#Smoker',$(this).closest('div')).val('true');
});
```

Both of these functions should be unnecessary though, since you shouldn't have more than one "#Smoker" element present in the DOM.

Comment: What if the partial view also has a #Smoker? Will it present as another id in the DOM?

Comment: You should try to avoid if at all possible, you should try to avoid having multiple elements with the same ID within the DOM as that would be invalid markup and could cause all sorts of unexpected behaviors. You might consider using a class attribute instead. All that aside, I believe that using the second approach of scoping your selector to a specific are (either a parent or another element) *should* work.